# JavaScript Game KeyDown event & keyboard actions not working

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning JavaScript and have been trying to put together a simple game before I move on. There are a few areas in my game that need adapting still... but my primary focus on is why my KeyDown event (with the additional arrow keyboard inputs) are not responding.  I've followed a few examples online and from what I have seen, it should be working...

Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
            //player (keyboard) input
            var keysDown= {};

            document.addEventListener("keyDown", function(e) {
                console.log('key press');
                keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
            }, false);

            document.addEventListener("keyUp", function(e) {
                delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
            }, false);

            //updating game objects + keysDown event
            var update = function (modifier) {

                if(38 in keysDown) {
                    interObject.y -= interObject.speed * modifier;
                }
                if(40 in keysDown) {
                    interObject.y += interObject.speed * modifier;
                }
                if(37 in keysDown) {
                    interObject.x -= interObject.speed * modifier;
                }
                if(39 in keysDown) {
                    interObject.x += interObject.speed * modifier;
                }

                if (
                    interObject.x === catchObject.x
                    && catchObject.x === interObject.x
                    && interObject.y === catchObject.y
                    && catchObject.y === interObject.y 
               ) {
               ++catchObjectCaught;
               rest();
               }
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've accidentally capitalized your 'keyDown' etc see fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u827H/1/

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    alert('works')
}, false);

document.addEventListener("keyDown", function(e) {
    alert('wont ever see this')
}, false);
```

They should all be lower case 'keydown', 'keyup'

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! I have tried this also..but still with no luck =[

Comment: @MarkAger have written a visual debugger for the code above http://jsfiddle.net/a5v4f/5/ and is working fine (only have added some display and a e = e || window.event check) Otherwise, can only be something else causing a problem other than you have provided